# Installing apex in solaris

Tags: oracle11g, solaris, oracle-apex

I neva worked with solaris or Linux before, and would like to find out how i can install oracle application express using command line in solaris, after i have installed my oracle database 11g in solaris aswell.

I already have an idea of how to install the database.

Answer (score 1):

i agree with the comments above, the apex installation guide on the oracle site is easy to follow, basically, you will have to:

- execute scripts in the oracle database (first create some tablespaces, then run an sql script that will install the apex module)
- deploy a file containing an apex "listener" that you will have to quickly configure, and run a WAR (java) file to run apex

and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Installation of Application Express (APEX) is largely Operating System agnostic. The process is based around running a number of scripts. When performing APEX installations, my primary tool is SQL Plus.

Depending on the version\edition of the Oracle Database you install, you probably already have a version of APEX ready to use. You can check which version of APEX your database has by running the following sql statement:

```
select version_no from apex_release
```

More information about installing Apex can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21673/overview.htm#BGECJIIF).

Answer (score 0):

the documentation on the oracle website is well done.
i installed apex on Solaris 10 and it works fine

basically, you just need to execute a few SQL scripts (create some users, import data), and afterwards run a java program to start the apex listener

check the documentation, it should be understandable even without too much of Solaris knowledge